# My Timer Not Reset and Not Stop

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I want to make Stop watch . On clicking on Start Button My timer is Start button on Click Stop my timer not stop. And on clicking Reset My timer reset then start again it is not right behaviour. Please help. I am newer in swift. Any help would be apperciated.Thamks in Advance

```
 class ViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet var label:UILabel?
        var time: Int!
        var appTimer :NSTimer = NSTimer()
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()
           time = 0
            label?.text = self.getFormattedString()
            // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        }

    }
    extension ViewController
    {
        func getFormattedString() ->NSString
        {

            var t :Int = time!
            var minQuotient :Int = time/600
            var  minRemainder:Int = time%600
            var secQuotient:Int = minRemainder/10
            var secRemainder:Int = minRemainder%10
            var  minString :NSString = NSString(format: "%d", minQuotient)
            var secString :NSString = NSString(format: "%d", secQuotient)
            if secQuotient < 10
            {
                secString = NSString(format: "0%@", secString)

            }
            var secRemainderString :NSString = NSString(format: "%d", secRemainder)
            return NSString(format: "%@:%@.%@",minString,secString,secRemainderString)



        }




        @IBAction func statrt()
        {
           appTimer.invalidate()
            var timer :NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector:Selector("stopWatch:") , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        }

        func stopWatch (theTimer:NSTimer)
        {
            time = time+1
            var b : String = self.getFormattedString()
            label?.text = b
        }



        @IBAction func stop()
        {
             self.appTimer.invalidate()
        }


        @IBAction func reset()
        {
             self.appTimer.invalidate()
           time = 0
            label!.text = self.getFormattedString()
        }
    }
```

Comment: White space is significant in Swift. You really should get into a habit of properly formatting your code. Following Apple's code examples would be a good start. Something like var timer :NSTimer gives me a headache. I would implicitly distrust any code with that kind of awful formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timer instance variable should really be optional and not initialised to an invalid timer instance:

```
var appTimer :NSTimer?
```

Then, when you create your new timer instance you need to store it into that instance variable instead of just creating it as a local variable in the function:

```
appTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.1, target: self, selector:Selector("stopWatch:") , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

I would also recommend that you try to be consistent about using `self.` so you know what you're doing in relation to instance and local state management.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing yourself between instance variables and plain method variables.

You don't always want a timer, so appTimer should be optional and nil, where you pointlessly create a timer. stop method invalidates any existing timer and sets the optional to nil. start method calls stop, then creates a new scheduled timer. And your deinit method calls stop.

Answer (score 0):

```
func start() {
    print("Fired")
    self.myTimer.invalidate()

    let ntimer :NSTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(10, target: self, selector:Selector("stopWatch") , userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    NSRunLoop.mainRunLoop().addTimer(ntimer, forMode: NSDefaultRunLoopMode)
}

func stopWatch() {
    print("stopped")
}
```

In console this was printing
Fired
stopped
stopped
stopped
you should find a place in your code stop the second timer.

Comment: Firedstoppedstoppedstoppedstoppedstoppedstoppedstoppedstoppedstoppedstoppedstop  continous print but not stop app

Comment: self.myTimer.invalidate() is the only api that can stop the timer.   @IBAction func stop()
        {
             self.appTimer.invalidate()
        }